# sftp (ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer)

Tags: ssh, sftp

I'm trying to `sftp` to a remote host, yet keep getting following output:

```
$ sftp -v X.X.X
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/alexus/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 56: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to X.X.X [X.X.X.X] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/alexus/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /home/alexus/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/alexus/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/alexus/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/alexus/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/alexus/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/alexus/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /home/alexus/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1
ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
Couldn't read packet: Connection reset by peer
$
```

I tried to `Google` it, but as of now I have not found a solution( any suggestions?

Comment: The server is accepting the TCP connection but closing it again before any SSH protocol interaction has a chance to occur. This commonly happens if the SSH server is crashing right after accepting the connection, for example.

Comment: posting destination logs might be helpful